# setTint of ShapeDrawable containing custom Shape?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Calling `setTint()` on a `ShapeDrawable` containing a custom `Shape` appears to have no effect on the color of the underlying shape.

**CustomShape.kt**

```
class CustomShape : Shape() {

    private val paint = Paint()
    private val path = Path()

    init {
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
    }

    override fun onResize(width: Float, height: Float) {
        // update path
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, this.paint)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
val shape = CustomShape()
val drawable = ShapeDrawable(shape)
drawable.setTint(Color.RED) // not working
someView.background = drawable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Use the `Paint` object supplied by `draw()`, which already has the anti alias flag applied, and will respect any methods you call on the `ShapeDrawable`.

---

The problem is that I was creating and using a new `Paint` object rather than using the one supplied in `draw()`. The rational for this was that I needed to turn on anti-aliasing, and I wanted to avoid doing so in the `draw` method.

Additionally, I was originally giving the `Paint` object a color directly in `CustomShape` before realizing it might be better/necessary to let the `ShapeDrawable` handle that.